# Add string into a text file at a certain string value

Tags: c++, qt

```
void elfenliedtopfan5_wep_adder_res::zonefilesetup(QString file)
{
    QFile inputFile(file);
    if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
       QTextStream in(&inputFile);
       while (!in.atEnd())
       {
          QString line = in.readLine();
          if(line.contains("scriptparsetree,scripts/zm/" + elfenliedtopfan5settings->value("ModName").toString() + ".csc"))
          {
              qDebug() << "We Hit" << line;
              break;
          }
          else
          {
              qDebug() << "We Did Not Hit" << line;
          }
       }
       inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

and what i wanting to do is add text under the line we hit so once found add text to file under that line

the file contents are

```
class,zm_mod_level
group,modtools

xmodel,skybox_default_day
material,luts_t7_default

// BSP
col_map,maps/zm/zm_elfenlied_v2.d3dbsp
gfx_map,maps/zm/zm_elfenlied_v2.d3dbsp

// Audio
sound,zm_elfenlied_v2

scriptparsetree,scripts/zm/zm_elfenlied_v2.gsc
scriptparsetree,scripts/zm/zm_elfenlied_v2.csc

// JARIK ELFENLIED LUA SETUP
scriptparsetree,scripts/zm/_zm_elfen_test.csc
scriptparsetree,scripts/zm/_zm_elfen_test.gsc
rawfile,ui/uieditor/menus/hud/T7Hud_zm_custom.lua
rawfile,ui/uieditor/widgets/elfenlied/zmElfenliedAmmoContainer.lua
rawfile,ui/uieditor/widgets/elfenlied/zmElfenLiedDefaultAmmo.lua
rawfile,ui/uieditor/widgets/elfenlied/zmElfenliedSpecialAmmo.lua
rawfile,ui/uieditor/widgets/elfenlied/zmElfenliedAmmoClipContainer.lua
rawfile,ui/uieditor/widgets/elfenlied/zmElfenliedGrenades.lua
image,elfenlied_special_ammo_stock_box
image,elfenlied_special_ammo_box
image,elfenlied_special_zombies_left_box
image,elfenlied_special_ammo_stock_box_red
image,elfenlied_special_ammo_box_red
image,elfenlied_special_zombies_left_box_red
image,elfenlied_anime_girl
image,gun_backing_main
// END

// ELFENLIED WEAPON HUDS.
image,uie_elfenlied_icon_p90_iw8_upg
image,uie_elfenlied_icon_pistol_standard

//ELFENLIEDTOPFAN5 MW19 PORTS
//MYSTERY BOX
stringtable,gamedata/weapons/zm/zm_levelcommon_weapons.csv

//WEAPONS
weapon,renetti
weapon,p90_iw8
weapon,p90_iw8_upg
//END

weapon,bo4_gks
weapon,bo4_gks_upgraded
weapon,aug_t8
weapon,aug_t8_upg
weapon,mp7_iw8
weapon,mp7_iw8_upg
```

the line i have found is

```
scriptparsetree,scripts/zm/zm_elfenlied_v2.csc
```

so want to find this line and under this line add more values but unsure how to accomplish this.

but unsure how to add strings under the line,
so once it finds that line

```
line in question found stript blablabla
// under this line in the file I want to add certain things but unsure how to approach this.
```

Comment: You can't add data into the middle of a file. Either read data from one file and write the same data, plus extra line, to another file. Or read the whole file into memory (say into a vector of strings) add the extra line to the vector, and then write the whole vector out to the file.

Comment: Yeah but how do you add a line to a vector at a certain place and overwrite the previous file. because not really seen any examples of this anyware in QT

Comment: If you read the file, then close it, then open it again for writing you will overwrite it. At least that's how standard C++ works and I'd be amazed if QT was any different. And adding a line at a certain place in a vector is just normal code, there's nothing special, just pick your place in the vector and add the line. Consult the QT documentation on vectors if you're not sure how.